# Function main received incorrect values from the subroutine

Tags: c

This code does not work - issues with passing the data from subroutine to main and allocating memory.

Computations are correct inside the subroutine but the values received by the main are incorrect - variables in main has random values, eg sRates.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include "sndfile.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sRates , sRatem , ret;
    long    nSamples=0, nSamplem;   
    float   *datas, *datam;


    printf("Read Test\n");
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expecting two wav file as argument\n");
        return 1;
    }


    ret =  readWav(argv[1], nSamples, sRates, &datas );
    if (ret != 0) {
    printf("Error\n");
    }
    // Output Info
    printf("Read %ld frames from %s, Sample rate: %d, Length: %fs\n",
        nSamples, argv[1], sRates, (float)nSamples/sRates);
    printf("Read %ld frames from %s, Sample rate: %d, Length: %fs\n",
        nSamples, argv[1], sRates, (float)nSamples/sRates);

//  free(datas);

    return 0;
}

int  readWav(char *fname, long *numFrames, int *sRate, float **buffer  ) 
{

    // Open sound file
    SF_INFO sndInfo;
    SNDFILE *sndFile = sf_open(fname, SFM_READ, &sndInfo);
    if (sndFile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading source file '%s': %s\n", fname, sf_strerror(sndFile));
        return 1;
    }


    printf("1Format of the audio file = %i\n", sndInfo.format);
    printf("2Number of channels = %i\n", sndInfo.channels);
    printf("3Sample Rate  = %d\n", sndInfo.samplerate);
    printf("4 Sample count  = %ld\n", (long)sndInfo.frames);
    sRate= sndInfo.samplerate;

    // Allocate memory
    buffer = (float *)malloc(sndInfo.frames * sndInfo.channels * sizeof(float));
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate memory for file\n");
        sf_close(sndFile);
        return 1;
    }

      // Load data
    numFrames = sf_readf_float(sndFile, buffer, sndInfo.frames);

    // Check correct number of samples loaded
    if (numFrames != sndInfo.frames) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Did not read enough frames for source\n");
        sf_close(sndFile);
        free(buffer);
//      return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("Successfully read file\n");
        numFrames = sndInfo.frames;
    }
    // Output Info
    printf("Read %ld frames from %s, Sample rate: %d, Length: %fs\n",
//      numFrames, fname, sndInfo.samplerate, (float)numFrames/sndInfo.samplerate);
        numFrames, fname, sRate, (float)numFrames/sndInfo.samplerate);


    sf_close(sndFile);
//  return(buffer);
    return(0);

}
```

Comment: `sRates` is local to main. Pass a pointer to it.

Comment: You haven't declared `readWav` before `main`.  If this compiles at all, it should issue a warning.  And that warning should be paid attention to.

Comment: If your function takes a `float *` argument, and you declared `datas` as `float *datas`, what do you think `&datas` will be? and on the other hand, you try to initialize `sRate` into the `readWav()` function, but you passed it's value instead of it's address, there is where you do need `&` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors in your code

1. You don't declare `readWav()` and you call it from `main()`, it's working by coincidence, namely because it does return `int`.
2. You are passing the address of `datas` to `readWav()`, note that `&datas` has type `float **` and `readWav()` is expecting a `float *`.

   If you had compiler warnings turned on, youl'd have noticed this.
3. You are passing the value of `nSamples` and `sRate` to `readWav()` and you are expecting the `nSamples` and `sRate` in your main to get initialized, you need to pass their addresses instead.
4. You check the return value of `readWav()` and yet you still try to acces the `datas` pointer.

This is a fixed version of your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sndfile.h"

int  readWav(const char *const fname, long *numFrames, int *sRate, float **buffer);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int   sRates, sRatem, ret;
    long  nSamples = 0, nSamplem;
    float *datas, *datam;


    printf("Read Test\n");
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expecting two wav file as argument\n");
        return 1;
    }


    ret = readWav(argv[1], &nSamples, &sRates, &datas);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("Error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Output Info
    printf("Read %ld frames from %s, Sample rate: %d, Length: %fs\n",
        nSamples, argv[1], sRates, (float)nSamples/sRates);
    printf("Read %ld frames from %s, Sample rate: %d, Length: %fs\n",
        nSamples, argv[1], sRates, (float)nSamples/sRates);
    free(datas);

    return 0;
}

int  readWav(const char *const fname, long *numFrames, int *sRate, float **buffer)
{
    // Open sound file
    SF_INFO sndInfo;

    if ((sRate == NULL) || (numFrames == NULL) || (buffer == NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid arguments passed to readWav()\n");
        return 1;
    }

    SNDFILE *sndFile = sf_open(fname, SFM_READ, &sndInfo);
    if (sndFile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading source file '%s': %s\n", fname, sf_strerror(sndFile));
        return 1;
    }

    printf("1Format of the audio file = %i\n", sndInfo.format);
    printf("2Number of channels = %i\n", sndInfo.channels);
    printf("3Sample Rate  = %d\n", sndInfo.samplerate);
    printf("4 Sample count  = %ld\n", (long)sndInfo.frames);

    // Allocate memory
    *buffer = malloc(sndInfo.frames * sndInfo.channels * sizeof(float));
    if (*buffer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate memory for file\n");
        sf_close(sndFile);

        return 1;
    }

    *sRate = sndInfo.samplerate;
    // Load data
    *numFrames = sf_readf_float(sndFile, *buffer, sndInfo.frames);
    // Check correct number of samples loaded
    if (*numFrames != sndInfo.frames) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Did not read enough frames for source\n");
        sf_close(sndFile);
        free(*buffer);
    }
    else {
        printf("Successfully read file\n");
        *numFrames = sndInfo.frames;
    }
    // Output Info
    printf("Read %ld frames from %s, Sample rate: %d, Length: %fs\n",
        *numFrames, fname, *sRate, (float)*numFrames/sndInfo.samplerate);

    sf_close(sndFile);
    return(0);

}
```

**Tip**: You should try to write your function in such a way that it has only one exit point, I like using `goto` for that, despite what religious programmers believe about `goto`, it makes your code more readable consistent and maintainable.

What I mean is you can have a label where you return the error code from the function and do all the cleanup, something like this

```
int function()
{
    /* set errorCode */
    if (firstFailureCondition == 1)
        goto cleanup;
    if (secondFailureCondition == 1)
        goto cleanup;
                 .
                 .
                 .
    if (nthFailureCondition == 2)
        goto cleanup;
cleanup:
    /* do your cleanup */
    return errorCode;
}
```

Comment: thank you. free(*buffer) is in the readWav when there is an error occurs - otherwise, is there a need to free .... if so when and where? Why there is no need to free the buffer if the program runs fine .. I guess if it is freed, then the main received NULL?

Comment: In readWav, why the ((sRate == NULL) || (numFrames == NULL) || (buffer == NULL)) is needed?

Comment: This line was moved down - *sRate= sndInfo.samplerate - wonder why? Also, I can not return the "sndInfo.samplerate" - I will have to assign it *sRate and then return - why?

Comment: Cleanup usually cleans the variables that are pointers if they are not NULL - eg float *datas, *datam; Curious are there any others needs to be freed?

Comment: Could I also use  float datas, datam; - without the pointer - but in readWav, I believe I will loose one "*" in front of buffer?

Comment: In readWav, why *buffer is needed -     *numFrames = sf_readf_float(sndFile, *buffer, sndInfo.frames);?  The original code where all are in one code, it is written like numFrames = sf_readf_float(sndFile, buffer, sndInfo.frames) and it works?

Comment: @user4504270 because you are passing pointers to the variables in `main()`, their addresses so you need to dereference the pointers to alter their values.

Comment: @user4504270 _Could I also use `float datas, datam;`_ I don't think so.

Comment: thanks for your help; I added a printf statement just before free(datas), printf("%d\t %f\n", i, datas[i]) or printf("%d\t %f\n", i, *(datas+i)) - it prints datas values but then ... segmentation fault. Compiler does not give any warning with -Wall option. I have another code where readWav is inside main - no segmentation fault with it. What might be causing it?

Comment: No worries - segmentation fault disappeared after I returned -1 inside cleanup.

Comment: @user4504270 did you know that you can accept the answers?

Comment: Thanks indeed - I accepted your answer - it was awesome - I feel like buying you a coffee - if u ever come to the north, let me know.

Comment: Why the following printf of the buffer in the readWav() causes segmentation fault just after printing the first row on the screen - it was placed just before sf_close(sndFile);:         for (i=0; i < sndInfo.frames ; i++) {
                printf("%d\t %f\n", i, *buffer[i]);
        }

Answer (score 3):

In C all arguments are passed by-value, so if you want a by-ref-like argument you must pass a pointer. And since you want to return a `float*` you need to pass a `float**`.

Actually you are passing that, but you are not using it correctly (please use `-Wall` or equivalent for your compiler to enable warnings).

The code should like more or less like this:

```
int  readWav(const char *fname, long *numFrames, int *sRate, float **buffer) 
{
    *buffer = malloc(...);
    //if you do not feel comfortable writing `*buffer` everywhere:
    float *data = *buffer;
    ///....
    *numFrames = sf_readf_float(...);
    ///....
    *sRate = sndInfo.samplerate;
    ///....
}

int main()
{
    long nSamples;
    int sRates;
    float *datas;
    ret =  readWav(argv[1], &nSamples, &sRates, &datas);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Based on the code of `readWav`, I suspect `nSamples` and `sRates` need to be passed to it by reference as well.

Comment: @Squirrel: Yes, you are right. I didn't read past the first few lines... I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: What is the logic behind your statement of "float *data = *buffer;"?

Comment: @user4504270: If you use the buffer only a couple of times, then it is worth nothing. But if you have to access the data a lot of times, to do calculations, for example, you'd have to write `(*buffer)[i]`. That can become cumbersome, and the helper `data` allows you to write `data[i]` instead.